# Should every `ftplugin/name.vim` need to define `b:undo_ftplugin`?

Tags: vim

Some scripts in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/`(for example `python.vim` and `ada.vim`) don't define `b:undo_ftplugin`. The `cpo` option default value is `aABceFs`.

When I `set ft=python`, then `set ft=css`. `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/css.vim` finish immediately. And `omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete` all the time.

Should every `ftplugin/name.vim` need to define `b:undo_ftplugin`?

---

This is  `/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim`:

```
" Vim support file to switch on loading plugins for file types
"
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last change:  2006 Apr 30

if exists("did_load_ftplugin")
  finish
endif
let did_load_ftplugin = 1

augroup filetypeplugin
  au FileType * call s:LoadFTPlugin()

  func! s:LoadFTPlugin()
    if exists("b:undo_ftplugin")
      exe b:undo_ftplugin
      unlet! b:undo_ftplugin b:did_ftplugin
    endif

    let s = expand("<amatch>")
    if s != ""
      if &cpo =~# "S" && exists("b:did_ftplugin")
        " In compatible mode options are reset to the global values, need to
        " set the local values also when a plugin was already used.
        unlet b:did_ftplugin
      endif

      " When there is a dot it is used to separate filetype names.  Thus for
      " "aaa.bbb" load "aaa" and then "bbb".
      for name in split(s, '\.')
        exe 'runtime! ftplugin/' . name . '.vim ftplugin/' . name . '_*.vim ftplugin/' . name . '/*.vim'
      endfor
    endif
  endfunc
augroup END
```

This is `/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/css.vim`:

```
" Vim filetype plugin file
" Language:         CSS
" Maintainer:       Nikolai Weibull <now@bitwi.se>
" Latest Revision:  2008-07-09

if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
  finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim

let b:undo_ftplugin = "setl com< cms< inc< fo< ofu<"

setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/ commentstring&
setlocal formatoptions-=t formatoptions+=croql
setlocal omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS

let &l:include = '^\s*@import\s\+\%(url(\)\='

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
```

---

If I `set ft=python`, then `set ft=css`. Vim cannot pass this test:

```
if &cpo =~# "S" && exists("b:did_ftplugin")
```

`b:did_ftplugin` doesn't get deleted, so `ftplugin/css.vim` finish immediately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:help undo_ftplugin` mentions:

> When the user does ":setfiletype xyz" the effect of the previous filetype should be undone.

Note that it says "should", not "must". But, according to the implementation

```
func! s:LoadFTPlugin()
    if exists("b:undo_ftplugin")
        exe b:undo_ftplugin
        unlet! b:undo_ftplugin b:did_ftplugin
    endif
```

a ftplugin *must* define `b:undo_ftplugin`, or its filetype settings cannot be changed any more via `:setf`. I think the documentation should point that out, and all ftplugins should indeed set `b:undo_ftplugin` (if only to an empty, no-op value).